# How do I get the base 10 log of an array?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'd like to get base-10 log of each element of an `Eigen::Array`.

To get the natural log, I simply do `array.log()`, as per the docs: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Array.html

But I see no mention of a base-10 log. Surely there's a way of doing this without writing my own?

Currently I'm doing something like `array.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(std::log10))` which seems to work fine, but I was hoping for something neater ***without compromising performance***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use math - Divide natural log(array) by natural log(10). This is why many calculators, etc. don't need to bother implementing every base. Because `log_b(a) = ln(a)/ln(b).`

My naive computational science guess is that this would be the fastest way to compute it anyway, e.g. since the Taylor expansion of `e^x` is simply `sum(x^n/n!)` over `n`, whereas for other bases there will be another exponential factor to calculate (possibly by multiplying into the `x` first). `e` is an elegant number in real analysis just like 2 is an elegant number in computer science.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned that performance is critical. This adds several 100s of clock cycles per element by introducing an additional division operation.

Comment: I suppose I could just multiply by 1/log(10)... that should be cheaper.

Comment: @Jason Dividing by log(10) is more expensive than multiplying by 1/log(10)?

Comment: Sort of. Multiplication is very cheap, so if we can evaluate 1/log(10) at compile-time and multiply every element then that's much cheaper than dividing by log(base).

Comment: Even the divide should be cheap compared to computing the elementwise log. Make sure you don't compute `ln(b)` for every element - i.e. evaluate that constant outside the loop.

Comment: @sfjac well it's a hundred clock cycles I'll never get back, I'll profile it and make a decision. Thanks for the help djechlin, it's a good idea I never would have thought of!